# How do i lock an asp.net page from multi-user editing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a page with a series of checkboxes that authenticated users can change.  I need to make this page only editable by one person at a time.  So if a user goes into it and edits one of the checkboxes, noone else can go into the page and change other checkboxes.

I thought about an edit page link and a readonly page link (all controls disabled), then set a database flag if user enters under edit mode, but my concern is i wouldn't know if the user changed something, then just x'd out of the browser/app, locking everyone else out.

This is an internal app to company. Has anybody done something like this?

Any ideas or thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have this functionality on an older ASP app.  The user will load data with some type of primary key.  We put in a DB entry to "lock" that page.  If they correctly move through the site, it will unlock the resources at that time.

Other users opening this page will receive indication that the page is locked and a read-only version is rendered.

It would be fairly trivial to code a unPageUnload AJAX call to reset the lock for browser closing.  We don't find this to be much of an issue and old locks are just cleared by an evening process if more than 4 hours old.

Our situation is where the pages are tied to specific regions of data.  If this is a general config screen, I think a more dynamic AJAX solution that pushed the updates back and pings for changes might make sense.  You would have to decide if you want to disable changes from others after the first update is received or implement collision detection for the data.

Some type of hashing of the page data would probably make this easier to detect changes.

Comment: Joe, did you ever have a problem with users simultaneously entering the page, where the db flag had been set for 2 users?  

I know it's a longshot, but I wonder if 2 users entered at the exact same time, if they would both get edit mode.

Comment: Not you implement a proper transaction in the db you can ensure only one person gets the lock

Comment: ajax javascript fires unload event even if browser is being x'd?

Comment: Fires, but you have no guarantee the request will complete.

Comment: Also, although the event will fire if the browser is closed through the UI, it won't fire if the process is forcibly terminated, as a result of user action (e.g. task manager) or browser crash.

Comment: Sorry, I've not been on, but the first comment is correct.  You need to do a table lock for the update, then a transaction that verifies that the resource is still available (you should have checked before locking) and inserts the lock.  This eliminates the possibility of a double up.

Answer (score 2):

You do what you said, but add a client side timer which will ping the server and tell you they are still there. If you don't get a ping within x mins you could let a new user go into edit mode but perhaps warn them (or not).

Answer (score 1):

What about letting all users edit this page and how your script check in for page updates? Just like SO does, while you are typing in an answer, an orange message appears above saying "At least one new answer has been posted". You could display something like "The page has been modified since you last opened it".

There was something like timer in ASP.NET AJAX. You could use that to talk to the server to send "IN EDIT" status updates. You can even go further. Say you send "LOCKOUT REQUEST" requests every 15 seconds asynchronously and you expect to receive the "LOCKOUT GRANTED" response from server. If the response hasn't been received, you disable all controls on the page until maybe the next request receives the confirmation (the previous message could have been lost in the network). This way, if one user closes the browser, the other won't have to wait many minutes or hours until they get the edit permission.

Essentially, you need a distributed implementation for a critical section concept. It maube a challenge to implement it over HTTP. But that's a very interesting challenge, isn't it?

Comment: SO? There are only checkboxes on the page that do not cause a postback, but they are in an update panel.

how would i check for the update?

Comment: StackOverflow=SO. You can use a javascript timer to initiate an Ajax request to poll for changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to prevent two users from updating a db record and over-writing each other, perhaps it would be easier to detect this than prevent it.

On strategy for this is to include a "version" field in the record, and save that in a hidden field when rendering the page.

Then you simply include that as a condition of your update (i.e. `UPDATE ... WHERE ID = myID AND VERSION = myversion`)  - if your update returns 0 rows, you know that someone else modified the data, and you can then decide what to do - reload the new data, offer the user a chance to compare them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about an alternative to an extended lock?

Since you appear to be manipulating relatively small amounts of data, it would be more polite to put an encoded version of original state of the data in a hidden form field (or a datestamp, though that's less reliable; a hash of the values would work for larger amounts of data). In a transaction, check the state of the database against the hidden form values; if the original record has changed since the user submitted the changes, you reject the update. If not, accept the update, and commit the transacation.

Comment: that's an interesting approach, but the users want to know if someone else (and who it is) is in the page, sort of like excel (person abc is editing, do you want to open page for readonly?)

Comment: You can still store that kind of information as part of the Edit action, and present it when other users attempts to edit the same record. Present a message "asdf opened this record 5 minutes ago. Are you sure you want to edit? If user asdf saves changes, your changes be rejected."

Comment: Also, if you're particularly worried about it, you can use javascript to poll for users who are currently editing the same record.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to have an Application variable that contained a map or dictionary of locked items.

So, when one user hits edit, add an entry to the AppVariable Map or Dictionary, with the Key set to the primary ID of the field being edited.  Then for all further requests, when they change between records, do a check of the ID within the map and if its being edited, Toggle off any update buttons.  If you want to do it AJAXy, add a timer and an UpdatePanel and poll to see when the lock is released, then refresh the page with the updated data and enable the update buttons again.

Or, as a slightly greater UI, allow the users to edit while waiting for the lock to release ( the Map item to be removed ), then when it is removed, compare the fields they have been working on, with the updated database values and allow them to overwrite/merge their changes.

The only real downside is, 1) You would need to create one Application level Dictionary or Map for each table that you want to lock/unlock.  2) If you get into a webfarm environment, it breaks and you would have to use a different system.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hadn't thought about an application var, we're on a web farm (5 servers), not sure that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Could as easily be done with a database table instead of as a Dictionary or Map, with some minor management code wrapped around it.